# Are all programming languages read in sequential order?

Tags: compilation, programming-languages, computer-science

I can't seem to find a direct answer on this. Using several search engines gives me very vague results, or only answers half the question.

So, to elaborate, when you write a program and it's compiled/interpreted, does the computer read each line sequentially in chronological order or does it skip around by default?

**Example:**
*Using C-style source because it was the first thing that came to mind.*

```
printf("I'm the first line of your program! Yay!");
printf("I'm the second, woo!");
printf("And I'm the third, yay!");
```

Above you can see there are three lines of code, and when run, they will be run in order and outputted to the console in said order.

I am assuming that, unless told to jump to a specific part of code within the source file, it will read each line of code in order. So is this how a program is interpreted in a computer, and do all programming languages get compiled/interpreted this way? Is how a program read language specific?

I know this is a basic question about programming languages and computer science, but I'd like some clarification and there aren't any concrete answers out there.

I probably worded the question incorrectly with my searches - that might be why I didn't find anything. Thanks!

Comment: Generally code is interpreted sequentially, yes.  Why wouldn't it be?  Granted, your question doesn't account for things like object-oriented code, asynchronous code, etc.  But when a compiler or interpreter reads a file, I would expect it to read that file from beginning to end.  What it *does* with the information it reads from that file is up to that compiler.  Is there a particular reason you're asking this?

Comment: Thanks! I know it's a generic question and will probably get downvoted, but I wanted to ask anyway. I just wanted to know to know.

Comment: I searched for this question since I was wondering why most machine learning models can be run and dockerized in a jupyter notebook, which is a "sequential interface" i.e. you run one thing at a time in order.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is highly dependent on some preconditions.

For a start, there exist so-called "scripting" programming languages.
The name itself pretty much sums the approach an *interpreter* of such
language takes when excuting programs written in that language: since they
are literally *scripts,* they are read in order and executed as
the interpreter reads out complete statements.

To put it differently, since a script is supposed to be read
from top to bottom, the definitions of various stuff must come
earlier than the places that stuff is used at.

Contrary to those, *compiled* languages usually grant more freedom
to the programmer. For instance, in modern languages it's quite often
possible to declare types textually "below" the places they are used
to declare/define variables of those types or other types making use
of those types.

But supposedly there exist a more deep distinction between "scripting"
and compiled languages: for the latter, the files *as a medium* are more
*declarative* rather than *imperative.*

For instance, take [Go](https://golang.org).
All the source code of a Go program is organized into "packages".
A package consists of all the source files located in a specific directory
and having a common package declaration.
Now any piece of the code located in the files of a particular package
is able to use any other *symbol* (a package-level variable, a type or
a function) of that package — no matter in which exactly file, and where exactly in that file that symbol is defined.

So that's how this works "at large".
If you're curious about how compilers precisely *work with the source files,*
then I think these days they tend to "slurp" then wholesale into memory
or read them in a streamed manner — parsing their contents as they go.

This simply does not matter because the compilers do not somehow directly
convert what's written in the source code files but rather build
the so-called abstract syntax trees out of these contents and then
convert those ASTs into the target machine (or VM) code, and this, in itself,
usually happens in several stages — all using their own convenient
intermediate representations.

#### TL;DR

The question of how a compiler reads a text file simply does not matter:
it's an uninteresting miniscule implementation detail. ;-)

Comment: I don't know, I think it's really interesting! This stuff is fascinating and I think having a deeper understanding of it will enhance the programming experience.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, unless Multi-threading is used, code statements will run in the "main" thread and be executed in order, and will not go to the next statement until the previous statement has completed.

If you use multi-threading there is no guarantee of the order of statements that occur in separate threads.

But within the same thread, statements are always executed in order.

Some high-level languages still support the "goto" statement, which allows you to jump around, but that is frowned upon because it creates "spaghetti" code, using loop constructs and calling methods is the preferred approach.

Comment: Neither loops, nor goto, nor threading will affect the order in which the source is *read* though.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all programming language implementations in wide use today read the *entire* source file into memory and then convert into one or more higher-level representations before they compile or execute *any* of it.

For example, if you run this Python program:

```
print "first line"
print print "<- error on this line"
```

Then the interpreter outputs:

```
  File "temp.py", line 2
    print print "<- error on this line"
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Notice that it does *not* print "first line" *before* reporting that error. It detected the syntax error in the second line before beginning to execute even the first line.

Back in the early days of computing when memory was scarce, some languages did parse and execute each line one at a time. But these days, that style is quite rare.