# Is async-await only used with promises?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I am using javascript.

My question comes from this scenario: I have a large array I am mapping through,

```
let myNewArray = myLargeArray.map(someFuntion)
console.log(myNewArray)
```

Is it possible that the mapping might take too long and that `undefined` might be logged? So should I use async-await or is it only reserved for promises?

Comment: Yes, async-await is *syntax sugar* to work with promises, your code is synchronous, and it won't log `undefined`. It will be processed synchronously, taking the time needed to end.

Comment: This executes in the order it is written. Execution is not random nor timing dependent. Maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/q/46304522/476.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible that the mapping might take too long

"too long" is subjective. The time it takes won't have any impact on the value you end up with though.

> that undefined might be logged?

`map` always returns an array, so no.

The array might contain undefined values though.

> So should I use async-await or is it only reserved for promises?

You can only usefully await a promise.

`map` will return an array, so you can't usefully await it.

If `someFunction` returns a promise, then the `map` will return an array of promises, which you could wrap with `Promise.all` which returns a promise that you could await if you wanted to log an array of resolved values instead of an array of promises.

Answer (score 2):

Map is synchronous.

It accepts a callback function `(someFuntion)` and always creates a new array.

The callback function `(someFuntion)` is not event driven. 

It is applied for every element in the array once in-order.

You will always receive an array and not undefined.
But values inside the returned array will depend on the callback function you provide to map.

If `someFuntion` returns nothing you will get array of undefined.

If returns promise then array of promise which can be resolved. `Promise.all`.